# Serverless deploy from M1 MacBook Pro causes invalid ELF header error

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, mongodb, serverless

I have a serverless REST api connecting to MongoDB atlas. When making changes and running `sls deploy` everything deploys as normal. But when I query the DB from postman, I was getting an error. The cloudwatch logs were as follows:

```
"errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header",
    "stack": [
        "Error: /var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)"
    ]
```

A developer took the same exact code ran `sls deploy` from his computer (Ubuntu) and everything works. I was able to send request and get results from the DB.

I tried `npm uninstall bcrypt` and `npm i bcrypt` then `sls deploy again` and still received the `invalid ELF header error`.

The issue is apparently the M1 MacBook. Is there a work around to handling this issue? I really don't want to rely on dev's running `sls deploy` every time I want to make changes to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using **bcryptjs** (npm i bcryptjs) instead of bcrypt package.

after install use it like this in the code `const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');`

It appears bcrypt fails on lambda because it uses node-gyp to build and install - not sure though will have to work though it.

Until then, bcryptjs works.